# How do we reconcile, probably non set-theoretically, that $S^1\times S^1$ is a torus, and $S^2$ is a sphere?

Tags: general-topology, spheres

The sphere is $S^2$ and the Torus is $S^1\times S^1$. I thought set theoretically atleast, that $X\times X = \{(x,y): x\in X, y\in X\} = X^2$. Is this notion that $T=S^1\times S^1$ and the sphere is $S^2$ where these aren't the same, a non-set theoretical notion?

Comment: There is a way that $S^n$ makes sense. The $0$-sphere is a pair of points, and the $n+1$-sphere is the topological "suspension" of then $n$-sphere. The suspension of a topological space $X$ is often written $SX$, so the $n$-sphere can bet written as then $S^n\{0,1\}$. If we write $\{0,1\}=S^0$... But that is just notational nonsense.

Answer (score 9):

It's just a different notation.  Most of the time, $X^2$ means $X\times X$, but in the special case $S^2$, it means something different.  More generally, when talking about geometric objects, it is common for a superscript to refer to the "dimension" of the object, rather than being an exponent.  It can be confusing sometimes, but usually in context it is easy to understand which meaning is intended by a superscript.

Comment: Okay, so it is just a notation that is convenient to remember, I see. Thanks for your answer